# References page include webography and bilbiography

Tags: bibliographies

I would to add a page named " References " to my paper, it will include a list of books and websites. This is my list of books and websites:

> **Livres :**
>
> Rancho Bernardo.Teradata Structured Query Language
>   Student Guide. CA U.S.A. Version 1.7.4. 2003-2007.890 pages
>
> SAP BO.Guide de l'utilisateur de SAP BO Universe Design Tool . Version 4.2 SP3.2017.552 pages
>
> SAP BO.Guide de l’utilisateur de SAP BO WEBI.Version 4.1.2015.644 pages
>
> **Sites et internets:**
>
> Introduction Générale sur Teradata : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_introduction.htm
>
> Architecture Teradata : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_architecture.htm
>
> Définition d’une dimension :http://decizia.com/quest-ce-quune-dimension/
>
> Définition d’un table de fait : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter
>   /fr/SS9UM9_9.1.1/com.ibm.datatools.dimensional.ui.doc/topics/c_dm_fact_tables.html
>
> Glossaire BI : https://dico.developpez.com/html/theme19.php

Here is my document, I would to include a webography part like bibliography.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anysize}
\marginsize{22mm}{14mm}{12mm}{25mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{teradata}
Teradata Structured Query Language,
\textit{Student Guide},
Rancho Bernardo , CA U.S.A,
Version 1.7.4,
2003-2007,890 pages.
\bibitem{univers}
SAP BO Universe Design Tool ,
\textit{Guide de l'utilisateur},
SAP BO , France ,Version 4.2 SP3,2017,552 pages
\bibitem{webi}
SAP BO WEB Intelligence ,
\textit{Guide de l'utilisateur},
SAP BO , France ,Version 4.1,2015,644 pages
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is a result :

[image]

Comment: What bibliography package do you use at the moment (if you use one)? What style. What document class do you use? Do you have a `.bib` file with the entries you show here? Please consider showing us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far. In case you don't know about bibliographies in TeX, have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Citations_and_Bibliographies and  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: I am edited a question , please help me to resolve it !

Comment: I would to put the report tomorrow , please help me !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you want. But you could try

```
\documentclass[svgnames,french,english,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{thebookbibliography}[1]
     {\section*{Livres}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebookbibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}

\newenvironment{thewebography}[1]
     {\section*{Sites et internets}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thewebography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\begin{thebookbibliography}{9}
\bibitem{teradata}
Teradata Structured Query Language,
\textit{Student Guide},
Rancho Bernardo, CA U.S.A,
Version 1.7.4,
2003-2007, 890 pages.
\bibitem{univers}
SAP BO Universe Design Tool,
\textit{Guide de l'utilisateur},
SAP BO, France, Version 4.2 SP3, 2017, 552 pages
\bibitem{webi}
SAP BO WEB Intelligence,
\textit{Guide de l'utilisateur},
SAP BO, France, Version 4.1, 2015, 644 pages
\end{thebookbibliography}

\begin{thewebography}{9}
\bibitem{teradata:intro} Introduction Générale sur Teradata :
\url{https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_introduction.htm}

\bibitem{teradata:arch} Architecture Teradata :
\url{https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_architecture.htm}

\bibitem{def:dim} Définition d’une dimension :
\url{http://decizia.com/quest-ce-quune-dimension/}

\bibitem{def:tab} Définition d’un table de fait :
\url{https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SS9UM9_9.1.1/com.ibm.datatools.dimensional.ui.doc/topics/c_dm_fact_tables.html}

\bibitem{gloss} Glossaire BI :
\url{https://dico.developpez.com/html/theme19.php}
\end{thewebography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thaaaaaaank youuuuuuuuu , it's working now (y) (y)